# Implicitly-declared boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source is deprecated

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, memory-mapped-files

I'm defining a struct as follows:

```
struct memory_dump {
    filesystem::path path;
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source mapped_file;
    memory_dump_type type;
    long long int offset;
};
```

However, `gcc` generates the following warning:

```
warning: implicitly-declared ‘boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source& boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source::operator=(const boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source&)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-copy]
   39 | struct memory_dump {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

This warning only occurred after upgrading my [`Boost`](https://www.boost.org) version from `1.62.0` or so to `1.72.0`. I resarched the warning but I didn't find any information about this particular `Boost` class, why the warning is generated and how to fix it. My goal is to store an instance of the [`mapped_file_source`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html) so I can access the contents of a memory mapped file efficiently.

Comment: Do you know what deprecated means?

Comment: @sweenish: Yes. It means it should not be used anymore. But what should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can se here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment

> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is
>   deprecated(since C++11) if T has a user-declared destructor or
>   user-declared copy constructor.

Which is the case in boost 1.72, as you can see:

```
    // Copy Constructor
    mapped_file_source(const mapped_file_source& other);
```

There is this copy constructor on line 187 of `boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp`

Comment: That's nice but do you also have a suggestion how to fix my code to be compliant?

Comment: I believe it is up to boost developers to fix this warning issue for upcoming releases. Your code is compliant, the boost code is not. However, you can mitigate this in several different ways, such as removing the copy constructor, or implementing the assignment operator yourself.

Comment: Also the code is already compliant. It may stop being compliant in the future which is why you get the deprecation warning